# How to start bootstrap collapsed target as collapsed when page load?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I know this question has been asked before but  I've read more then 10 posts and still cannot figure out how to start my row collapsed so that when I click on it they expand.

```
<table class="soloduoquadtable">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" class="soloduoquadtable" style="background-color:#aef54d; padding-left:9%;"><b>DUO</b><img src="2people.png" style="height:100%; width:12%;" align="right" /></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="border-right:1px black solid; border-top:1px black solid; text-align:center; font-size:20px; background-color:lightgrey; padding-top:10px;"><b>Rank 250 <pre>Top 1%</pre></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="soloduoquadtable">Win%<pre>10</pre></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="soloduoquadtable" style="border-right:1px solid black; width:50%">KDA<pre>25252</pre></td>
                            <td class="soloduoquadtable">Top 10%<pre>15</pre></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr id="demo" class="collaspe">
                            <td  colspan="2" class="soloduoquadtable">Hello</td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>
                    <input  type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="width:inherit;" value="MORE INSIGHTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example of Data table with Collapse Row using bootstrap:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.table').length > 0) {
    $('.table .header').on("click", function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("active", "").nextUntil('.header').css('display', function(i, v) {
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
      });
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.table tr:not(.header) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="2">Header 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="2">Header 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="2">Header 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="2">Header 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: THIS DOESNT USE BOOTSTRAP

Comment: @HENRY.LES-it use bootstrap.I have added it in code snippet.Check now

Comment: @HENRY.LES can you explain?

Comment: @HENRY.LES-Thanks I understand you want to use bootstrap js.I updated my code sample.Also please add bootstrap details in your question

Comment: I do not need to use accordion. Please see my updated above and if you can tell me how to make so that when the page opens it starts collapsed.